# FFMPEG - Overlaying video with transparency, alpha has strange threshold

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transparency, alpha, alphablending

I'm attempting to overlay an Apple ProRes 4444 video with a alpha/transparency onto a normal video. However, upon inspecting the final output from FFMPEG, compared to the same files overlaid on top of one another and rendered in Final Cut Pro, there is a discrepancy in how they render the edges around the object.

Screenshot comparison:

[image: Screenshot comparison]

Additional closeup:

[image: Additional closeup]

Here is my input:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i background.MOV -x264opts colormatrix=bt709 \
    -i alpha_object.MOV -x264opts colormatrix=bt709 \
    -filter_complex " \
        [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080[top]; \
        [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080, \
             colorchannelmixer=aa=1.0[bottom]; \
        [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1" \
    -vcodec libx264 -qp 15 -an -shortest output.MOV
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Is there a option within FFMPEG's available filters that I'm missing?

All files are ingested and rendered in 1920x1080.

Comment: Usually, this has to do with whether the alpha video has premultiplied pixels or unmatted but will need a sample of the alpha video to test. Also, the the `x264opts` apply to the encoder and aren't per-input options. If the files are already 1080p, remove the scale filters. The ccm filter isn't needed. And although it doesn't make a difference here, the 2nd input to the overlay filter is the video on top. Here, the labels are incorrect, although the input order is correct.

Comment: [Here's a link to the alpha video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAKw9627o1CU2plMm9Wb1daaTg/view?usp=sharing), the original file can be downloaded in the top right corner.
Good call, thanks for clearing up my confusion on the `x264opts`, I wasn't aware that wasn't a per-input option.
Some of my files are in 4k, setting the scale filters because I plan to batch process the operation later.
Ah! Good call on the labels as well, you're right, they should be reversed.